# Ansible overiridng security group rules when being used with loops

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying to add rules to security group. There is no error while running, but after the successful run, the security group only has the last CIDR added to it.

```yaml
- name: Edit security group to accept connections from other sg groups in other availability zones
  amazon.aws.ec2_group:
    name: nodes-sg
    description: nodes security group
    vpc_id: "{{vpc_id}}"
    region: "{{aws_region}}"

    tags: 
      Name: nodes-sg
    rules:
      - proto: udp
        ports:
          - 30303
        cidr_ip: "{{item.cidr}}"
        rule_desc: "{{item.desc}}"
      
      - proto: tcp
        ports:
          - 30303
          - 26656
        cidr_ip: "{{item.cidr}}"
        rule_desc: "{{item.desc}}"
      
      - proto: icmp
        from_port: 8 # icmp type, -1 = any type
        to_port:  -1 # icmp subtype, -1 = any subtype
        cidr_ip: "{{item.cidr}}"
        rule_desc: "{{item.desc}}"
      
  when: vpc_cidr != item.cidr
  loop:
    - { cidr: '10.92.0.0/16', desc: 'peering ap-northeast-2 mainnet-v1-1' }
    - { cidr: '10.115.0.0/16', desc: 'peering sa-east-1 mainnet-v1-1'}
    - { cidr: '172.98.0.0/16', desc: 'peering eu-north-1 mainnet-v1-1'}
    - { cidr: '10.212.0.0/16', desc: 'peering ca-central-1 mainnet-v1-1'}
    - { cidr: '172.112.0.0/16', desc: 'peering ap-southeast-2 mainnet-v1-1'}
    - { cidr: '10.159.0.0/16', desc: 'peering eu-west-2 mainnet-v1-1'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ansible is effectively "last commit wins", unless you were to intersperse your `ec2_group:` with an `ec2_group_info:` and merge the results manually, ansible thinks you already have the full story and does not merge by itself

What you'll want is to do all that filtering business either in a `vars:` block or in a separate `set_fact:` and then only at the last moment assign it to the `rules:` param of `ec2_group:`

```yaml
  tasks:
  - name: declare ec2_group rules for not my vpc_cidr
    set_fact:
      ec2_group_rules: '{{ ec2_group_rules_yaml | from_yaml }}'
    vars:
      cidrs:
      - { cidr: '10.92.0.0/16', desc: 'peering ap-northeast-2 mainnet-v1-1' }
      - { cidr: '10.115.0.0/16', desc: 'peering sa-east-1 mainnet-v1-1'}
      - { cidr: '172.98.0.0/16', desc: 'peering eu-north-1 mainnet-v1-1'}
      - { cidr: '10.212.0.0/16', desc: 'peering ca-central-1 mainnet-v1-1'}
      - { cidr: '172.112.0.0/16', desc: 'peering ap-southeast-2 mainnet-v1-1'}
      - { cidr: '10.159.0.0/16', desc: 'peering eu-west-2 mainnet-v1-1'}
      ec2_group_rules_yaml: |
        {% for item in cidrs | rejectattr("cidr", "eq", vpc_cidr) | list %}
        - proto: udp
          ports:
            - 30303
          cidr_ip: "{{item.cidr}}"
          rule_desc: "{{item.desc}}"
        
        - proto: tcp
          ports:
            - 30303
            - 26656
          cidr_ip: "{{item.cidr}}"
          rule_desc: "{{item.desc}}"
        
        - proto: icmp
          from_port: 8 # icmp type, -1 = any type
          to_port:  -1 # icmp subtype, -1 = any subtype
          cidr_ip: "{{item.cidr}}"
          rule_desc: "{{item.desc}}"
        {% endfor %}
```

that `ec2_group_rules_yaml:` business is a concession to keeping the parameterized version legible, but one cannot (easily) use `set_fact:` and `loop:` without some silliness

As I mentioned, it's also entirely possible to skip the `set_fact:` and just put those `vars:` on your `ec2_group:` and do:

```yaml
  amazon.aws.ec2_group:
    name: nodes-sg
    description: nodes security group
    vpc_id: "{{vpc_id}}"
    region: "{{aws_region}}"

    tags: 
      Name: nodes-sg
    rules: '{{ ec2_group_rules_yaml | from_yaml }}'
```

but that form is harder for me to test locally :-D